# how can launch an Android service from a html link?

Tags: android, html, service

I know there is a way to launch an application (activity) from a html link url ( for example to click a url link in email)  like below:  (www.youtube.com is just an example, I have my own host)

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
   <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

but this is launching an activity, is there any way to launch my service (silently in the background)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Register an activity with that intent-filter, start the service from the onCreate of your activity, and call finish(). By calling finish() before onCreate finishes, the activity should never be visible to the user.